# Выравнивание логотипа по центру меню с названием сайта

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Есть вот такой код navbar.
Вот что должно получиться на выходе [image: navbar]

Не понимаю как это сделать, выровнял всё по центру, отступ от логотипа 150px влево и вправо.
Меню будет адаптивным, не думаю что через absolute будет правильное решение...
Может кто-то подсказать как лучше выполнить данный код, чтобы соответствовало скрину ?
Буду признателен ;)

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.nav-menu__item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.nav-menu__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
}

.nav-menu__item .active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5363db;
}

.nav-menu__item_center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 135px;
}

.nav-menu__item.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#" class="active">About us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Reservation</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item logo"><img src="//www.anyway.website/d/logo.png" alt="YOGA" class="logo"></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#" class="nav-menu__item_center">YOGA</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Очень подозреваю, что YOGA должно быть частью картинки. Или у вас есть такой шрифт?

Comment: @andreymal шрифт такой "ChampagneLimousinesBold"

Comment: Если логотип является единственным местом, где этот шрифт используется, я бы всё равно сделал картинкой

Comment: А вообще как-то странно, что на вашей картинке логотип не выровнен по горизонтали. Точно нужно именно так? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ey7f.png

Comment: @andreymal то я криво скриншот шапки сделал, прошу прощения :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu__item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.nav-menu__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
}

.nav-menu__item .active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5363db;
}

.nav-menu__item_center {
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  padding: 0 150px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo__link {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo__image {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#" class="active">About us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Reservation</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo__link">
          <img class="logo__image" src="//www.anyway.website/d/logo.png"
          alt="YOGA" class="logo">
          YOGA
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
      <li class="nav-menu__item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav
```

Comment: Вы задали ссылке inline-block, а логотипу - block, это и всё ?)

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE нет, здесь ещё картинка и YOGA завёрнуты в один общий li

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE, поместил все в один `li`, обнулил у него `margin` и убрал     у `ul` `padding`.

Comment: @E_K, благодарствую, вопрос решен ;)